# Ruby: Comparison of String to zero failed (Argument Error)

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, comparison

I am trying to sort the following array of songs:

```
array = ["Jurassic 5 - What's Golden - hip-hop",
           "Action Bronson - Larry Csonka - indie",
           "Real Estate - Green Aisles - country",
           "Real Estate - It's Real - hip-hop",
           "Thundercat - For Love I Come - dance"]
```

What I want is to sort the array based on the name of the song. The name of the song is the middle text of the each element for example:

```
array = ["Jurassic 5 - **What's Golden** - hip-hop"]
```

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
array.sort do |a, b|
 a = a.split(" - ")
 b = b.split(" - ")
 a[1] <=> b[1]
 a = a.join(" - ")
 b = b.join(" - ")
end
```

The result array I want is:

```
  array = ["Thundercat - For Love I Come - dance", 
           "Real Estate - Green Aisles - country", 
           "Real Estate - It's Real - hip-hop", 
           "Action Bronson - Larry Csonka - indie", 
           "Jurassic 5 - What's Golden - hip-hop"]
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
  ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed
    from (irb):52:in `>'
    from (irb):52:in `sort'
    from (irb):52
    from C:/Ruby23/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

I have checked the values to be compared in PRY and both are strings.

```
    pry(#<MusicLibraryController>)> a.class
    => Array
    pry(#<MusicLibraryController>)> a[1].class
    => String
    pry(#<MusicLibraryController>)> b.class
    =>Array
    pry(#<MusicLibraryController>)> b[1].class
    => String
```

Questions:

1. Why am I getting this error ?
2. What should be done to get rid of the error?
3. Can you please suggest a better approach for sorting an array based on a specific part of its element? Like in this case a sub-string of the string element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you are returning one string in your sort's block and it needs an integer

2) return an integer

3) sure, like

```
array.sort { |a, b| a.split(" - ")[1] <=> b.split(" - ")[1] }
```

but this is better

```
array.sort_by { |item| item.split(" - ")[1] }
```

[Read the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sort) for `sort` method

Comment: my pleasure Sir ;)